# Only select shortest value for column with multiple values on Wikidata query

Tags: filter, sparql, wikidata

I have the following query:

```
SELECT ?admin ?name ?abbr
WHERE {
  VALUES ?admin { wd:Q771 }
  ?admin wdt:P131 ?country;
         wdt:P17 ?country.
  OPTIONAL { ?admin wdt:P1813 ?alias. }
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".
    ?admin rdfs:label ?name.
    ?alias rdfs:label ?abbr.
  }
}
```

This retrieves the administration in `VALUES` with its English name and abbrevations, if available. For example:

| admin | name | abbr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| wd:Q771 | Massachusetts | MA |
| wd:Q771 | Massachusetts | Mass. |

Now I would like to filter it such that only the shortest abbreviation is displayed. For the above output, for example, I would only get one record, the one with `MA`. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `SELECT ?admin ?name ?abbr
WHERE {
  VALUES ?admin { wd:Q771 }
  ?admin wdt:P131 ?country;
         wdt:P17 ?country.
  OPTIONAL { ?admin wdt:P1813 ?abbr. }
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".
    ?admin rdfs:label ?name.
    
  }
  filter not exists {
              ?admin wdt:P1813 ?abbrOther 
              filter(?abbr != ?abbrOther && strlen(str(?abbrOther)) < strlen(str(?abbr)))
            }
}`

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work nicely. If you add it as an answer I will mark it as accepted.